# Change figsize in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

It seems that the figsize option only changes the ratio of the height to width. Atleast this is the case when using jupyter notebooks. Here is an example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np

plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
plt.plot(np.arange(1,10),np.arange(1,10))
plt.show()
plt.figure(figsize=(24,6))
plt.plot(np.arange(1,10),np.arange(1,10))
plt.show()
```

I was hoping that figsize intended inches, not a relative ratio. How would you go about enforcing that in python/ jupyter notebooks.

Answer (score 3):

If you use a large `figsize`, say `figsize=(50, 5)` you will notice that the lines, the labels, everything is incredibly thin and small with respect to a plot with normal size.

This happens because you are using widths that are not compatible with the width of the output cell
and the notebook just **scales down the figure** to make it fit in the output cell.

<del>To have the behavior you asked for, you need a horizontal scrolling capability in the output cell.  I don't know of a `nbextension` that can enable horizontal scrolling in output cells.</del>

---

After a bit of experimenting, it looks like using the `nbagg` backend

```
%matplotlib nbagg
```

gives you a scrollable output cell, and an interactive one as well, inside the notebook and possibly it is what you want.

---

*Addendum*

I've found [this issue](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/2109) on IPython's github, with a request for horizontal scrolling in output cell — as you can see it's dated 2012 and there is no followup of sort.

Answer (score 1):

```
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(16, 8)
```

Comment: I'm afraid in jupyter notebooks this doesn't do any different to the figsize option above. Just changes the ratioi

Answer (score 0):

After change `figsize` the figure size do changed when the parameter in a certain range.In my condition,size not growing after size above (24,8).When it's still below the range the size do increase.It's base on your displayer **dpi**, you can set the dpi in `figure` but eventually it's rely on your hardware.
The figaspect is set by [matplotlib.figure.figaspect](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.figaspect)

If you save figures to files use `savefig`,you will see the image size increase also.